# Typescript - How do I remove a value from a hashmap?

Tags: typescript, hashmap

I found this post about implementing a hashmap in typescript, and I've got that working, except for removing something from the hashmap.

[TypeScript hashmap/dictionary interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211175/typescript-hashmap-dictionary-interface)

I add something by doing `Input.keys[event.key] = event.keyCode;` to add a key to my abstract Input class's keys field that is a hashmap. How can I remove something from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your not doing this as just an exercise it might be useful to look into [Map()](https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/maps/) I think it should provide the needed functionality